# Markdown reformatting is broken if a list item starts with a block element

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting, list, stacks-editor

The new/stacks editor, when switching from source mode to Markdown mode, breaks alignment of list items `<li>` if it begins with a block-level element (`<blockquote>` or `<pre>`).

For example, the following content renders just fine:

```markdown
1. > Blockquote content

   Regular paragraph
```

When switching to Markdown mode, it produces an empty line out of nowhere before the blockquote:

> [image]

Then back to source mode, it becomes this:

```markdown
1. 

   > Blockquote content

   Regular paragraph
```

Which is already broken as it makes the blockquote no longer a child of the list item. Accordingly, after switching again to Markdown mode and back, it becomes its final form:

```markdown
1. 

> Blockquote content

Regular paragraph
```

This is the same for code blocks (i.e. `<pre>`):

````markdown
1. ```c
   int main() {}
   ```

   Regular paragraph
````

After switching once:

````markdown
1. 

   ```c
   int main() {}
   ```

   Regular paragraph
````

After switching twice:

````markdown
1. 

```c
int main() {}
```

Regular paragraph
````